# MySQL: BOOLEAN (aka tinyint(1)) vs BIT

Tags: mysql, types

What is the difference between BIT and BOOLEAN?

Comment: BOOLEAN is just an alias for TINYINT(1), while BIT(n) actually allows you to save `n` bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tinyint(1) is an integer type with a defined *display width* of 1. The BIT data type represents bit-field values which can have from 1 to 64 bits.

The storage size of tinyint is always 1 byte while the storage size of BIT(n) is approximately INT((n+7)/8) bytes

You can write to a BIT field using a special notation e.g. b'1111', don't think you can use this with INT/TINYINT fields